# How to maintain ssh connection for multiple scp transfers?

Tags: centos, ssh, files, scp, arch-linux

I'm using the scp command to copy files from my **local machine (ArchLinux)** to my **server (CentOS 6.5)**.

But for each scp command a new connection is established and although **I'm using SSH keys for authentication** the proccess is taking to much time.

So, is there any way to maintain the connection and make multiple transfers over it?

Comment: Please show us the commands you are running.

Comment: Probably you can use ControlMaster/ControlPath options in ~/.ssh/config for that particular CentOS server.

Comment: @iain Im using 'scp -Cp /path/to/local_file user@host:remote/path/'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Nobody took the opportunity to complete answer and I didn't find any duplicate, so here we go.</sup>

You can set up `~/.ssh/config`, with these options:

```
Host machine1
  HostName machine1.example.org
  User yourusername
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-something
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 10m
```

Then make sure you `mkdir ~/.ssh/controlmasters/` and from that time, your connections to `machine1` will persist for 10 minutes so you can issue more sessions or data transfers during one connection.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly will this do? I mean what is ControlMatser and ControlPath? And is it possible to make the connection presist for undefined period and then close it manually?
Finally, Do I add these lines to the local or remote machine?

Comment: The options are described well in manual page (`man ssh_config`). It is local configuration (server has to support it, but openssh shipped nowadays do). Yes, you can set up infinite time (`Yes` value) and close it using `ssh -O exit machine1`.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.